# What do I do if ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (32,) and (31, 5)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

```py
csv_data = pd.read_csv("master.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data,
                  columns=['year', 'suicides/100k pop', 'age', 'country', 'sex'])

us_rates = df['country'].values == 'United States'
df_us_rates = df.loc[us_rates]


teen_rates = df_us_rates['age'].values == '15-24 years'
df_teen_rates = df_us_rates.loc[teen_rates]


boy_rates = df_teen_rates['sex'].values == 'male'
df_boy_rates = df_teen_rates.loc[boy_rates]

girl_rates = df_teen_rates['sex'].values == 'female'
df_girls_rates = df_teen_rates.loc[girl_rates]

years = csv_data['year']
no_dups = []



print(df_teen_rates)
for year in years:
    if year not in no_dups:
        no_dups.append(year)

plt.plot(no_dups, df_boy_rates)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to plot:

- `no_dups`, which is a 1D list of 32 values
- against `df_boy_rates` which is a 2D dataframe with 31 rows and 5 columns

Assuming that the column you're interested in is 'suicides/100k pop', modify your code like this:

```
df_boy_rates = df_teen_rates.loc[boy_rates, 'suicides/100k pop']
```

Also, you have to check why there is one more element in `no_dups`